# SQL Server 2008 shrink database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a 1 TB database file that I am cleaning up. I need to now shrink this file. I am currently running this statement:

```
USE [DW_Zone]--databasename
GO

DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(N'DW_Zone')
GO
```

I'm trying to shrink the database, but it has been running for over 3 days now, what is the issue?

If I stop this process then what will the effect on my database? And any other way to shrink this database?

Please help me...

Comment: Can you retrieve any log output? Can you verify that something is still happening?

Comment: Small note - a reason it could be taking so long is due to the number of indexes and PK/FK constraints.  Next time, drop them all before the shrink and then recreate after.

Answer (score 1):

We can shrink only the transaction log file(.ldf) not the data(.mdf). You can use the following query to shrink your corresponding database.

```
USE [DBName]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DBName] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT
DBCC SHRINKFILE(DB_log, 1)
ALTER DATABASE [DBName] SET RECOVERY FULL WITH NO_WAIT
GO
```

We can set the SQL jobs to run this query frequently whenever the log file reaches the maximum size(which we can set based on the disk space).

Comment: Actually both can be shrinked

Answer (score 0):

> If I stop this process then what will the effect on my database?

DBCC SHRINKDATABASE operations can be stopped at any point in the process, and any completed work is retained.